# inner network access with ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

I use putty on windows vista to establish ssh connection to ubuntu on ec2.

I want the ubunto to do wget on some iis url in my vista. This url is not exposed to the web. Is  there a way to establish such network between the host and guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use ssh tunneling to achieve this. In your putty config go to:

Connection>SSH>Tunnels

The add a remote tunnel with source port of whatever you like (eg 8888) and destination of localhost:80.

- Untick "Local ports accept connections from other hosts"
- Untick "Remote ports do the same"
- Source port: 8888
- Destination: localhost:80
- Choose "Remote"
- Choose "Auto"

Then when you hit http://localhost:8888 on your remote server you'll actually be getting your local machine's web server on port 80.

Comment: wget localhost:8888 gives me "failed: Connection refused". On the tunnels tab I used all the default settings, maybe I should change something?

Comment: Untick "Local ports accept connections from other hosts"

Untick "Remote ports do the same"

Source port: 8888

Destination: localhost:80

Choose "Remote"

Choose "Auto"

Comment: it is not checked by default

Comment: I've updated my answer with full steps

Comment: I've just installed Apache on my local Windows machine and tested this myself from a remote server to check I'm not going crazy and it works!

`# telnet localhost 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: Ah OK. Leaving it on local instead of remote will have created the tunnel the other way round, so port 8888 on your localmachine will end up going to port 80 on the destination server.